# Last_insert_id() devuelve 0, a pesar que si inserta

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
//METODO 

  $conex  = mainModel::conectar();

        $sql=$conex->prepare("CALL i_componentesnew(:descripcion,:nparte1,:nparte2,:nparte3,:marca,:id_unidad_med,:nserie,:medida,:categoria)");
        $sql->bindParam(":descripcion",$datos["descripcion"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":nparte1",$datos["nparte1"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":nparte2",$datos["nparte2"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":nparte3",$datos["nparte3"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":nserie",$datos["nserie"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":marca",$datos["marca"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":categoria",$datos["categoria"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":medida",$datos["medida"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":id_unidad_med",$datos["id_unidad_med"]);

        //$sql->execute();
        if($sql->execute()){
            $id = $conex->lastInsertId();
            return $id;
        }else{
            $conex->rollback();
    }
```

**lastInsertId()** me devuelve 0 a pesar que inserta, no se que podría ser.

Comment: Te falta la instrucción de inicio de la transacción no? Es decir tu beginTransaction

Comment: si, solo que no lo he copiado, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se debe a que lo que estas ejecutando es un `CALL` de un proceso almacenado imagino, php al ver que no es un INSERT no te esta devolviendo nada en el `lastInsertId`, lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar manualmente el lastInsertId como consulta

```
$statement = $conex->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id");
$statement->execute();       
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = $result["id"];
return $id;
```

Comment: Gracias Victor tenias razon ya obtengo el id. tambien lo habia intendado de la misma manera pero algo hice mal al parecer. Gracias

Comment: Esto `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id` se puede poner también en la última línea de la SP, de ese modo ésta retornará el último ID y evitarás tener que preparar y ejecutar una consulta adicional, lo cual es mucho más costoso.