# beginTransaction(), PDO transacciones MYSQL, no genera cambios

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
    $conexion = mainModel::conectar();
    try{
        $conexion->beginTransaction();
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare("CALL i_pagos(:fk_idreg_factura,:fecha_reg,:fecha_pago,:monto_pagado,
        :saldo,:moneda_pago,:metodo_pago,:comision,:pago_documento,:fk_idusuario)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":fk_idreg_factura",$datos["id_reg"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":fecha_reg",$datos["fecha_reg"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":fecha_pago",$datos["fecha_pago"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":monto_pagado",$datos["monto_pagado"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":saldo",$datos["saldo"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":moneda_pago",$datos["moneda"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":metodo_pago",$datos["metodo_pago"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":comision",$datos["comision"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pago_documento",$datos["registrar_pago"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":fk_idusuario",$datos["fk_idusuario"]);
        $stmt->execute();//me da true
        $conexion->inTransaction(); //me da true
        $conexion->commit(); //me da true
        $result = true;
    }catch (PDOException $ex) {
        //$result=false;
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        $conexion->rollback();
    }finally{
        return $result;
    }
```

Al iniciar el beginTransaction() no me inserta el procedimiento almacena, pero si lo quito si inserta, he probado con otro codigo.

```
  try{
        $conexion->beginTransaction();
        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO t_moneda 
        (nombre,simbolo,pais,countryCode)VALUES('yENG','L','reino unido','E');");
        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO t_moneda ( 
        nombre,simbolo,pais,countryCode)VALUES('pesos','E','reino unido','E');");
        $conexion->commit(); 

    }catch (PDOException $ex) {
        //$result=false;
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        $conexion->rollback();
    }
```

este codigo si inserta y tiene el begintransaction y commit, al parecer no reconoce las transaccion cuando uso SP algo parecido pase con usar la funcion lastinsertid()

Comment: podrías revisar esto: https://riptutorial.com/php/example/4186/database-transactions-with-pdo, puede que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, lei todo el post pero no encuentro el error.

Comment: Te podría ayudar más si supiera de donde sacas los `$datos[]`  de cada campo (los listas, los recorreas) o que hace tu procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: $datos es un array   $datos = [
            "id_reg"=>$id_reg_factura,
            "fecha_reg"=>$fecha_reg,
            "fecha_pago"=>$fecha_pago,
            "monto_pagado"=>$monto_pagado,
            "saldo"=>$neto_pagar-$monto_pagado,
            "moneda"=>$moneda,
            "metodo_pago"=>$metodo_pago,
            "comision"=>$comision,
            "registrar_pago"=>$registrar_pago,
            "validar_pago_detalle"=>$validar_pago_detalle,
            "fk_idusuario"=>$usuario
        ];

Comment: el problema es que yo comento las transacciones begin y commit y si me registra.

Comment: También probaste sacando solo el `$conexion->inTransaction();` ?

Comment: si la verdad, ya lo intente

Comment: me parece que beginTransaccion no ejecuta en consultas preparadas

Comment: He estado buscando y solo me parece información banal. Sabes te aconsejo que uses las transacciones dentro del SP.

Comment: si eso lo estaba haciendo, tengo que ver la manera validar el commit y el rollback

Answer (score 0):

```
 $stmt = $conexion->prepare("START TRANSACTION");//Remplaza $conexion->beginTransaction();
 $stmt->execute();
 //CODIGO DE ARRIBA
  $stmt = $conexion->prepare("COMMIT");
  $stmt->execute();
 catch{
     $stmt = $conexion->prepare("ROLLBACK");
     $stmt->execute();
  }
```

En conclusion el beginTransaccion no soporta procedimientos almacenados, o tal vez yo lo este hacien mal, esperare respuestas, por ahora esta fue mi solucion.
tuve un problema similar con lastisertid() dejo el enlance
[Last_insert_id() devuelve 0, a pesar que si inserta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317108/last-insert-id-devuelve-0-a-pesar-que-si-inserta/317137#317137)